# Date component value on devices with different locale's

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, calendar

I can't find documentation on this.

When using `Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())`, can I always be sure that I'll get a number between 0 and 23? I'm relying on a 24-hour format for hours, but I'm unable to find whether depending on timezone/locale or anything else I could potentially get an hour between 0 and 11 instead.

**EDIT**

Sorry for the typo in the title :)

Comment: as per my knowledge Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) always return in hrs between 0-23. For 0-11 we have to specify the format

Comment: YES, it will return a value between 0 - 23. You can check this by changing your device time and locale to match some location where it is afternoon, if your current time is not.